# How to SELECT last calender month (not the interval)?

Tags: mysql

I have date time field called transaction_date, in a report i need to select last calendar month, how do i do this ? (this should work for a month like January too)

I came up with following but this only works if the month is NOT january,

```
SELECT SUM(amount)  AS pay_month FROM `users_payment`  WHERE  MONTH(transaction_datetime)= MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(transaction_datetime)=YEAR(NOW())
```

there are lot of examples using INTERVAL functions but this only select the time interval not the calendar month as i wanted too..

like

```
SELECT SUM(amount)  AS `year_month` FROM `users_payment`   WHERE  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) < transaction_datetime
```

but this is not what i want, i want to select sales sum of the DECEMBER only last year (remember there are other years too in the table which i dont want i.e 1979, 1981...etc)

same report next section, i need to select last 2 calender months, I dont know have any idea on how to do this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following

```
SELECT SUM(amount)  AS `year_month` FROM `users_payment`
WHERE MONTH(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) = MONTH(transaction_datetime)
```

The above should work to show previous month; it does not distinguish between years however.

On second thought, I see what you are trying to do - To get all the transactions for a given month.  Try something like this instead.

```
SELECT SUM(amount)  AS `year_month` FROM `users_payment`
WHERE transaction_datetime BETWEEN date_format(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')
   AND last_day(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

This will list all the transactions for the previous calendar month.  Alter the `INTERVAL` values to select multiple months.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this--

```
SELECT SUM(amount)  AS pay_month FROM `users_payment`  WHERE  
PERIOD_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m'), -1) = DATE_FORMAT(transaction_datetime,'%Y%m')
```